# Study about real analysis

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I know about inverse function theorem. But got stuck in a case that
 "How continuity of Df is a necessary assumption for this theorem ?" 
Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x)=|x|$ at $x=0$. It has right and left derivatives at $x=0$. Therefore, $\mathrm{D}f$ always exists, except that it is not continuous at $x=0$ and it has a jump from $-1$ to $+1$ there.

It is obviously never invertible at any neighborhood around $x=0$ because it will always fail the horizontal line test in any neighborhood around $x=0$, no matter how small the neighborhood is. The existence of a counter-example when the continuity of $\mathrm{D}f$ is not assumed shows that the continuity of $\mathrm{D}f$  is indeed a necessary condition for the theorem to hold.

If you have a particular proof and you want to explicitly see where the proof goes wrong when that assumption is not true anymore, you should mention the proof in your question.